# missing the pin on google map

Tags: javascript, html, api

My map is missing the pin drop, I tried figuring out the api page but i cant seem to get the pin on my google map. here is my code so far. If anyone has any ideas on how to get that pin on there I would appreciate it.

```
    <!-- GOOGLE MAPS -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
      function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.6676314, -117.6598071),
          zoom: 14,
          scrollwheel: false ,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is creating a map centered on lat 33.6676314, lng -117.6598071 and I'm pretty sure the map is showing fine. You haven't yet created any markers, so go on and make one. The code to achieve that, in its most basic form is

```
function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.6676314, -117.6598071),
          zoom: 14,
          scrollwheel: false ,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
        var newmarker= new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.6676314, -117.6598071),
                map: map 
            });
      }
```

please note that the map property of a marker should point to whatever variable you named your map to. For example:

```
        var AwesomeMap = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
        var newmarker= new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(33.6676314, -117.6598071),
                map: AwesomeMap 
            });
```

Position can be any valid LatLng object or LatLng literal. The following, for example, is valid too

```
            var newmarker= new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat:33.6676314, lng:-117.6598071},
                map: AwesomeMap 
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out
http://www.x2tutorials.com/tutorials/google-maps-v3/using-map-markers.php

If this is not what you are trying to achieve, please elaborate on the problem you are facing